# Apache redirect for non-wildcard SSL cert not working

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect

I have a SSL certificate for `example.com` but is not valid for `www.example.com`. I'm attempting to put in an Apache rewrite rule as so to redirect all traffic to the non-www domain name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

The rewrite is working when I do a curl for https://www.example.com, it shows a 301 redirect as expected:

```
curl -I https://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;
Location: https://example.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

But the browser is still showing a certificate error, and does not redirect to the non-www URL. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you access https://example.com ( via curl and via a browser )

Comment: I http redirecting to https. This part is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could add a **SAN (Subject Alternative Name)** entry to your certificate for www.example.com. So, same cert will be used for both of those domains. Do a web search abt SAN to get more understanding. Some Ref. [What is SAN](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no solution fix your problem unless you go for installing an SSL Certificate on your Apache Server.